# Postfix Catchall - Avoid Spam

Tags: centos, email, postfix, smtp, spam

I've 2 accounts on my **CentOS** server configured with **catchall** email accounts. Lately I've been receiving bounced emails with virus that were supposedly sent from my server account, Ex: `somestragename@mydomain.com`.  The postfix mail server is configured to allow only **authenticated users** to send mail but I'm wondering if the emails were sent from my server.

How can I avoid this bounced emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is probably not sending these messages, but you should check the messages headers and your maillogs to be sure.

These messages are probably [`backscatter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(e-mail)) from [`joe jobbing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_jobbing) spammers.
[`SPF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) is probably the quickest way to mitigate this, though [`DKIM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) is arguably better. (You can do both.)

Comment: I've enabled both, thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use catchall email accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not an options for me. I need the catchall to track who sells my email accounts or websites that  get hacked. This means that I use a different mail account for every provider, ex dropbox@domain.com, facebook@domain.com.

Comment: Again, don't use catchall email accounts. They are not good for the purpose you are abusing them for. Create email aliases explicitly.

Comment: As I said previously, not an option for my @Michael. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case, you will have to read a whole bunch of spam. It certainly _is_ an option, you just don't want to do it for some reason you have not disclosed.

Comment: It would be annoying having to create email alias for every junk website that need to register, it's simply not practical for me.

Comment: Why not? I do it all the time for my personal email domain. How practical is it for you to read all that spam?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40062/discussion-between-pedro-lobito-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: I don't read any spam Michael. They're automatically filtered. I just want to know if the emails are being sent from my sever or simply have my accounts on `Reply To:`. Is there any way to check this? I want to make sure my ips don't get blacklisted.